# Use SET ARITHABORT ON in stored procedure

Tags: c#, sql-server, azure, winforms, azure-sql-database

I am using a SQL Azure database.

When I pull records,it is faster in SQL SERVER management studio. but the same query is running slow on WinForms app.I always use stored procedure for SQL operations.

My Stored procedure typically like this

```
 ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[sp_SELECT_WorkFlow_Status_Filter]
    @Division                TINYINT,
    @IsdeptIDSelected        BIT ,
    @IsMachineStatusSelected BIT ,
    @IsPrioritySelected      BIT ,
    @DeptID                  NVARCHAR (20) ,
    @Priority                NVARCHAR (10) ,
    @Status                  NVARCHAR (20)
 AS

SET NOCOUNT ON

SET ARITHABORT ON -- USE HERE ????

BEGIN
  ---SELECT SQL
  -----
  -----
  --RETURN RESULTS
END
```

So if I use `SET ARITHABORT ON` something like this, will get performance as SSMS in WinForms?

Comment: I don't see how this can be answered, as we have no idea what your query looks like, its complexity, amount of data being manipulated, etc. But it seems like, if you write a stored procedure, then you place your divide-by-zero check there. And if you run your query from code, you place it in code.

Comment: add some [mcve]

Answer (score 0):

Try with `OPTION(RECOMPILE)` and see if it speeds up. Then research about parameter sniffing

Answer (score -1):

Running anything will be quicker on the server than locally, when dealing with any cloud-based products. Add it to the stored procedure.

Comment: Not sure how you can make such a blanket statement. Plus, the OP's question is really unclear (and seems like placing a divide-by-zero check would go wherever the query is, whether in code or in stored proc, regardless of performance).

Comment: I was interpreting his question as, basically, he's going to run a stored procedure either way via C#, is it quicker to set options for the stored procedure from C# or the stored procedure.